# how to get true or false with attribute searching in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

count() does not respond. I want total number of value(numeric), but it returns object.

```
console.log("print the count value");

// Product_order.find(callback).count("")
Product_order(callback.count(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

can you explain your problem with more details if product_order is table then  you should find count like

```
product_order.count('field_name')
```